# Flask WTForms w/ SQLAlchemy: UnmappedInstanceError when storing a form in a database

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am unable to store a form in a **sqlite3** database using Flask-SQLAlchemy. My `views.py` is throwing the error below when I attempt to store the form.

```
UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'app.forms.Survey1' is not mapped
```

### Views.py

```
@app.route('/survey_1/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def survey_1():
    form = Survey1(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print form
    db.session.add(form)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('Survey1.html', title='Survey', form=form)
```

### Models.py

```
class Survey1(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    gender = db.Column(db.Integer)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    education = db.Column(db.Integer)
    language = db.Column(db.String(20))
    db = db.relationship('Database', backref='survey1', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, gender=None, age=None, education=None, language=None):
        self.gender=gender
        self.age=age
        self.education=education
        self.language=language

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

### Forms.py

```
class Survey1(Form):
    gender=fields.RadioField('X', choices=[('Y','Y'),('Z','Z')],validators = [Required()])
    age=fields.RadioField('X', choices=[('Y','Y'),('Z','Z')], validators=[Required()])
    education = fields.RadioField('X',choices=[('Y','Y'),('Z','Z')],validators=[Required()])
    language = fields.TextField('Native Language', validators=[Required()])
```

How can I store this form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's methods only work with SQLAlchemy objects - your issue is that you are passing an instance of WTForms `Form` class (which SQLAlchemy doesn't know how to persist to your database).  You can map from your WTForms class *to* your SQLAlchemy object by using [`Form.populate_obj`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj) once you change your `Form` declaration to match the types in your `Model` class (`gender`, `age`, and `education` are all marked as `Integer` in your `Model` class, but are `String` fields in your `Form` class).

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    model = models.Survey1()

    form.populate_obj(model)

    db.session.add(model)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply, I see where the fundamental problem was. I was hoping that you could elaborate a bit on the models.Survey1(), I don't understand how this is mapping a WTForm obj to a SQLAlchemy obj. Also, are the radio buttons always stored as strings, as I believed that it could be integers too.

Comment: It's actually `form.populate_obj` that is mapping the data in `form` to the empty `model`.  For your form fields that are supposed to be integers, you can use [`coerce=int`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.RadioField) as an argument to the field constructor: `fields.RadioField("An integer field", coerce=int, choices=[...])`